# Issue updating Individual rows in SQL database with checkbox in PHP

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I have a table I'm trying update individual columns with checkboxes. I've gotten it to where I can update all of them at once but not one by one. I'm still pretty new to php so any help would be greatly appreciated.

**PHP**

```
$tsql = "SELECT * FROM time_events WHERE Date >= '$date' and Date < 
DATEADD(DAY,7,'$date') and user_id = '$employeeid' ";
try {
$getResults = $conn->prepare( $tsql);
$getResults->execute();
$rowCounter = $getResults->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);
} catch (Exception $ex) {
echo($ex->getMessage());
}

$count=$getResults ->rowCount();

if(isset($_POST['updatestatus'])){
  for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
    $eventid = $_POST['event_id'][$i];
    if ($eventid != null){
      $approved = !empty($_POST['approved'][$i]) ? 1 : 0;
      $flag = isset($_POST['flag'][$i]) ? 1 : 0;
      print_r ($count);

      $tsql = "UPDATE time_events SET flagged = convert(int,'$flag'), approved = convert(int,'$approved') WHERE event_id = convert(int,'$eventid')";

      try {
        $getResults = $conn->prepare( $tsql);
        $getResults->execute();
      } catch (Exception $ex) {
        echo($ex->getMessage());
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
  <input type="hidden" name="event_id[]" id="event_id" value="<?php if(empty($row['event_id'])){echo null; } else  {echo $row['event_id'];}; ?>"/>
  <td class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1"><?php echo $row['day']; ?></td>
  <td class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2"><?php echo $row['date'];?></td>
  <td class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1"<?php echo $style; ?>><?php echo $row['start_time']; ?></td>
  <td class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1"<?php echo $style; ?>><?php echo $row['end_time']; ?></td>
  <td class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1"<?php echo $style; ?>><?php echo $row['job_number']; ?></td>
  <td class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4"<?php echo $style; ?>><?php echo $row['description']; ?></td>

  <td class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 text-center"><input type="checkbox" class="chk_boxes1" name="flag[]" value="<?php echo $row['event_id']; ?>" title="Flag Time Entry" <?php if ($row['flagged'] == 1) echo "checked='checked'"; ?></input ></td>
  <td class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 text-center"><input type="checkbox" class="chk_boxes2" name="approved[]" value="<?php echo $row['event_id']; ?>" title="Approve Time Entry" <?php if ($row['approved'] == 1) echo "checked='checked'"; ?></input></td>
```

Comment: Can you check whether the post sent to the server is correct, to see whether the problem is in outputting the proper checkboxes or performing the proper updates

Comment: The update statements aren't being sent correctly. I think it has to do with the fact that there are rows in my table that dont have event_id's. I don't want to update the rows that don't have them.

Comment: Could you show table schema from `time_events` table? Is there any error when you excuted the code?

Comment: The updates execute without issue. Its just setting the correct row to the correct value. There seems to be a disconnect between to event_id and the checkbox but I can't figure it out.

Comment: What does `$_POST['event_id'][$i]` contain for these events? Really `null` or the string "null"?

Comment: Really null when a event_id isn't present